# upload through paperclip using form,corresponding js.erb does render the content as desired and shows connecting on the title bar of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, paperclip

My  scenario is like this,
I have made a form and in that form there is a file field to upload images,video,audio through paperclip and on complete of my submission of form to a particular action i have a corresponding js.erb which run on completion of my action.It runs fine when i upload a image the form gets submitted and code written takes the user to another page,but when i upload a video or audio the form gets submitted,it gets updated in the database but my js.erb doesn't get execute the desired result,even though on the development.log shows that the js.erb corresponding to that action has been called,connecting shows upon the title bar of browser.

action on which it goes when form gets submitted

```
 def home_content_save
    @home = HomeContent.new(params[:home_content])
    if (@home.save)
      @home_page_after_login_content = HomeContent.where(:after_login_home_content=>true)
      @home_page_before_login_content = HomeContent.where(:after_login_home_content=>false)
    else
      @message = @home.errors.full_messages
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

home_content_save.js.erb

```
<% if @message.empty? %>
    $('.content').html("<%=escape_javascript(render 'admin/shared/home',home_page_after_login_content: @home_page_after_login_content,home_page_before_login_content: @home_page_before_login_content)%>");
    $('#spinner').hide();
<% else %>
    $('.success').html(<%= @message %>).show();
    $('#spinner').hide();
<% end %>
```

view

```
<%= form_for(@home, url: @home.new_record? ? home_content_save_path : home_content_update_path(id: @home.id), html: { :multipart => true }, remote: true) do |f| %>

    <div class="upload-preview">
      <%if @home.new_record?%>
        <img src='/assets/logo_img.png' width:"198" style="width:200px;height:150px"/>
        <label><%= t('admin.upload_image')%></label>
      <%else%>
        <%=image_tag @home.photo.url(:medium), style: "width:200px;height:150px;"%>
        <label><%= t('admin.change_image')%></label>
      <%end%>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-upload" style="width:56%;">
      <%= f.file_field :photo, class: 'file'%>
      <div class="fake-file">
        <input disabled="disabled" id="image_file">
        <span class="browse"><%= t('admin.browse')%></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <%unless @home.new_record? %>
      <audio width="258" height="200" controls>
        <source src="<%=@home.audio.url%>" type="audio/mp3">
          <source src="<%=@home.audio.url%>" type="audio/ogg">
          <%= t('admin.y_brower_not_support_video_tag')%>.
      </audio>
    <%end%>

    <label><%= t('admin.upload_media1')%></label>  *Only Ogg Format
    <p id="path_audio" style="display:none"><%= t('admin.drive_path')%></p>
    <div class="custom-upload" style="width:56%;">
      <%= f.file_field :audio, class: 'file_audio'%>
      <div class="fake-file">
        <input disabled="disabled" id="audio_file" >
        <span class="browse"><%= t('admin.browse')%></span> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <%unless @home.new_record? %>
      <video width="258" height="200" controls>
        <source src="<%=@home.video.url%>" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="<%=@home.video.url%>" type="video/webm">
          <%= t('admin.y_brower_not_support_video_tag')%>.
      </video>
    <%end%>

    <label><%= t('admin.upload_media2')%></label>*Only Ogg Format
    <p id="path_video" style="display:none"><%= t('admin.drive_video_path')%></p>
    <div class="custom-upload" style="width:56%;">
      <%= f.file_field :video, class: 'file_video'%>

      <div class="fake-file">
        <input disabled="disabled" id="video_file" >
        <span class="browse"><%= t('admin.browse')%> </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%=f.submit 'Publish', class: 'btn green'%>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because the `.js.erb` isn't running code doesn't mean it isn't loading (`your code could be incorrect`)

Have you tried adding an alert to your `home_content_save.js.erb`, like so:

```
#home_content_save.js.erb
alert("<%=j @message.empty? ? 'empty' : 'not empty' %>");
```

This won't fix the problem, but will give you a much clearer picture of whether your JS is firing or not. If you say it's loading the `js.erb` file in your logs, you may find the issue could be your code is not running correctly & should be refactoreed

--

You'll also want to look at using `<%=j %>` to escape your JS!